# How to yield in map?

Tags: react-native, yield, array.prototype.map

I am using react native to build my application and I am trying to convert my variables to camelCase using the code below

```
export default function formatToCamelCase(inputObject: {[key: string]: any}) {
  let snakeKeys = Object.keys(inputObject);
  let newObject = {};

  for (let key of snakeKeys) {
    if (typeof inputObject[key] !== 'object') {
      newObject[parseToCamelCase(key)] = inputObject[key];
    } else if (inputObject[key] !== null && !Array.isArray(inputObject[key])) {
      newObject[parseToCamelCase(key)] = formatToCamelCase(inputObject[key]);
    } else {
      newObject[parseToCamelCase(key)] = inputObject[key];
    }
  }
  return newObject;
}

export function formatArrayToCamelCase(inputArray: Array<{[key: string]: any}>) {
  return inputArray.map((object) => {
    return formatToCamelCase(object);
  });
}
```

And I am trying to call the formatArrayToCamelCase method in the function here (in a separate file):

```
import formatToCamelCase, {formatArrayToCamelCase} from '../helpers/formatToCamelCase';

export function* fetchWeighInWeighOutEvent(action: FetchWeighInWeighOutEventAction): any {
  ...
  Object.values(locations).map((location) => {
    let timeslotsArray = location.timeslots;
    if (timeslotsArray.length > 0) {
      //Problem here - shows that yield is a reserved word
      let camelCaseTimeslots = yield call(formatArrayToCamelCase, timeslotsArray);
    }
  });
```

I was unable to put the yield call in the .map, when trying to run the code, I get the following error:
**SyntaxError: yield is a reserve word**

How can I overcome this issue so that I can call the formatArrayToCamelCase function and convert my array accordingly?

Comment: Uh... I think the syntax of the `yield` command is `yield (expression)`, you're not supposed to put it after a `let` command.

Comment: Suggest using `<!-- language-all: lang-js -->`. Also, no text as image please.